# Why is the TFS 2012 server locking up when checking in a deleted folder?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, visual-studio-2015

We currently have an issue with our TFS server locking up whenever any of our developers attempt to check in a pending delete on a folder, however, this is a relatively new (within the last couple of months) issue, and we have been struggling to determine the root cause.

Essentially, the process that is occurring is something like this:

1. Create folder in TFS.
2. Branch from Dev trunk, creating the branch in the new folder.
3. Make any code changes in branch.
4. Merge changes from branch into Dev trunk.
5. Delete branch.
6. Realize we no longer need the folder.
7. Delete the folder.
8. Attempt to check-in folder deletion.
9. TFS server locks up, not allowing any operations to be performed until the server is restarted.

So, I am looking for two answers:

1. Why is TFS locking up when attempting to check in a folder deletion?
2. What can we do to resolve the issue?

A little bit more info:

- This problem occurs for every user, including out TFS administrator(s).
- It may occur even when there was never anything placed in the folder, but we haven't attempted that, so that we can avoid having to restart the server.
- This has not always been an issue on the server, as it use to be relatively common for us to delete folders.
- This issue occurs regardless of how the delete is being performed (VS2012, VS2015, command line, etc.).
- We primarily work with a single trunk, but have potentially hundreds of branches being created over the course of a month.
- The solution contains roughly 20-25,000 files, currently.

Comment: What's the detailed error message and ID when you do the check in?

Comment: There is no error message, it completely locks up the server, making others unable to perform even basic operations.  That being said, I did some testing the other night after everyone else went home, and found that eventually the delete operations do complete, but they take excessively long to finish.  The one folder that I deleted took almost an hour to check in.  So, I am leaning toward something being corrupted or network traffic volume (or both) being the cause of this.